# How to use Q objcts in annotate tortoise

Tags: python, django, pydantic, tortoise-orm

So simply i have my models Announcement, User, FavoriteAnnouncement

```
class FavoriteAnnouncement(CoreModel):
    user = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.User', related_name='favorites')
    announcement = fields.ForeignKeyField(
        'models.Announcement',
        related_name='favorites'
    )
```

i want to add an annotated field is_user_fav : Optional[bool]

I found a soluition in django
(

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(is_user_fav=ExpressionWrapper(
            Q(...),
            output_field=BooleanField(),
        ),)
```

)

How can i do a similar thing in TortoiseORM ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CASE statement instead of a Q expression. Here's an example that gives you the boolean result you're looking for:

```py
from tortoise.expressions import Case, When

queryset = queryset.annotate(is_user_fav=Case(
    When(..., then=True),
    default=False
))
```

You can treat `When` basically the same as `Q`, it just also allows you to specify what the value should be when that condition is met.